# dpkg: error processing package bind9 (--configure)

Tags: bind, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, debian-jessie

In a Raspbian is the following error appearing whenever you run apt-get, how to solve it?

```
Setting up bind9 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u16) ...
dpkg: error processing package bind9 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 102
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bind9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In /etc/bind there are the following files:

```
root@rpi:/etc/bind# ls -1
bind.keys
db.0
db.127
db.255
db.empty
db.local
db.root
named.conf
named.conf.default-zones
named.conf.local
named.conf.options
rndc.key
zones.rfc1918
```